# App using Google Maps API v2 keeps crashing

Tags: android, google-maps

When I run it on my phone it works fine. The problem is that I want to run it on another ANdroid device with Android 2.3.7. It doesn't even show me the map. Instead it crashes and gives me this message: "The application Google Play services (process com.google.android.gms) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." with a button "Force close".

[image: Here's what I get in the LogCat:]

Comment: pld post the stacktrace instead of snap shot. also post the relevant manifest and java codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your manifest.xml. Have you added following permissions.

```
<permission
        android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.ijoomer.src.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```